# Instantiating int templates based on data

Tags: c++, templates

I am using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) as a linear algebra package. There they have fixed size matrix types, defined something like:

```
template<class TNumber, size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix
{...}
```

so becasue I am using only vectors and square matrices, most of my classes ended up being similar templates:

```
template<size_t K>
class MyClass {...}
```

The dimension K will actually depend on data loaded from a file. Is there any reasonable way to instantiate these templates with a dynamic size K, or do I have to have a switch statement:

```
switch(dim) {
case 1: MyClass<1>...
case 2: MyClass<2>...

default: //too much data
}
```

?

Comment: If it is important to you that your software support sizes dynamically, but the programming interface is static, you can try to employ "just in time" code. You create a dynamic shared object at run time, then load it.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are instantiated at compile time, not run time. Therefore, you can't have a template instantiation based on run-time data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an upper limit to the number of dimensions, you can create proxy classes to map the dimension to an index and use the index instead. That is not a pretty solution, but it might work.

```
  class Proxy{
  protected:
        OpaqueAllocator *allocators[10];
  public:
        Proxy(){
             allocators[0] = new SpecializedAllocator<0>();
             allocators[1] = new SpecializedAllocator<1>();
             allocators[...] = new SpecializedAllocator<...>();
             allocators[9] = new SpecializedAllocator<9>();
        }

        static OpaqueAllocator* getAllocator(const size_t index){ return allocators[index]; }
  };

  // usage:
  int test = 2;
  // allocate a two dimensional array:
  Container *c = Proxy::getAllocator(test)->allocate();
```

The main problem is that you need an opaque class for the main container. You can still preserve type safety in the background, but the readability will suffer a bit.